# Whose underwear is this?

Tags: dc, character-identification, justice-league, merchandise

Okay, this is a bit different....

My son recently got underwear for his birthday.  The underwear came in a set of 5, packaged as *Justice League* underwear.

On the packaging, you can see The Flash, Superman, Green Lantern, and Batman.  Each of those four have a clearly-recognizable pair of underwear: white and red with the lightning bolt logo for The Flash; blue and red with the "S" logo and shield for Superman; green and black with the lantern ring for Green Lantern; black with the bat symbol for Batman.

The fifth pair, however, has me confused.  It  is white with black borders, and has what appear to be golden "V's" (although half of them are upside down).  Does this pattern have any association with the Justice League, or a specific member of the Justice League?  My son wants to know who that underwear belongs to.

[image]

Comment: I just have to give you props for sticking with new and unused.... (I also wish I could give more than one up-vote, the title alone gets one.)

Comment: My son got the same set, and we had the same question.  Sadly, I didn't think to ask it here and we just spent several frustrating hours googling, before coming to the same conclusion.

Comment: When I saw this question's title, I thought at first that I was at [gaming.stackexchange](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9713/the-master-list-of-questions-which-really-need-context).

Comment: I asked this exact same question on social media after getting these for my son last year. :)

Comment: When I was much younger I had all the "Challenge of the Super Friends" action figures, along with the collectors case.  The outside of the case had every logo for every DC hero and villain at the time, and I would obsessively name off every one to anyone who would listen.

Comment: Boo to [that edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/68005/revisions).

Comment: Did you by any chance observe any 'side effects' when sleeping in Aquaman....

Comment: Make sure your son doesn't wear the underwears outside, especially the one with S symbol.

Comment: @NewtScamander No danger of that... He's outgrown these by now :)

Comment: I am very sure your son loved this underwear...if he ever wet the bed, he would only need to say: actually, I didn't do it, it was *Aqua*man! (although he *would* have all his comic books scanned before he reads them, just in case...)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

That would be [Aquaman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaman).  The logo is a stylized "A", usually seen as a part of his belt buckle.

[image: Aquaman Logo]

[image: Aquaman]

Comment: "OK folks, we need a fifth Justice League hero for our 5-pack underwear special. What do we do?" ...[This looks like a job for Aquaman!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThisLooksLikeAJobForAquaman)

Comment: He didn't even get his face on the front of the package, so it really does seem like a last-minute addition.  "We can't possibly put Wonder Woman on boys' underwear, and nobody knows who the heck Martian Manhunter is.. who's left?"

Comment: The merits of putting Aquaman on something that (depending on the age) may routinely become wet throughout the night makes me question the decision. Perhaps they should have just sold packs of 4 or 8.

Comment: I assume the underwear doesn't shrink after being washed.

Comment: It might be water proof.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should be proud of the fact that my highest rated answer is one dealing with underwear identification...

Comment: [Oh, man. Aquaman sucks.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBLaRSmqGS8)

Comment: Ah, of *course* it would be Aquaman. Poor Aquaman.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103987/is-the-aquaman-symbol-an-a

Answer (score 52):

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.arts.comics.dc.universe/3RVoDArFZ5A) Google search led to the Aquaman picture below.

It is from his Belt.

[image]

Comment: And, for comparison, the lesser known hero _Butt-Man_ on the right. He would wear those briefs on his face.

Comment: Yes, I know he was kidding, but if you can't place him, on the right is Black Manta, probably Aquaman's best known villain. Which, perhaps, explains why I find it necessary to clarify.

Comment: that looks like a custom black manta. or else it was made by someone who's never seen Black Manta in any other media.

Comment: Now you can't search aquaman without 200,000 images of jason momoa.