# Identify this arrowhead-like gold icon on a blue background

Tags: marvel, dc, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, object-identification

I came across this list of upcoming comic movies:

[image: Grid of 25 superhero movies from 2015 through 2019]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

But I don't recognise this icon, can anyone tell me what/who it represents?

[image: arrowhead labeled "July 2018"]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: reminded me of [Whose underwear is this?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68005/whose-underwear-is-this)

Comment: Just a tip (atleast in chrome). When you right click an images and select "search on google for this image", Google searches for similar/related images. In this case it refers you to a ton of Aquaman content.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I haven't actually seen this logo used in conjunction with the film, but **Aquaman** is [currently slated to be released on July 27, 2018](https://screenrant.com/tag/aquaman/).

You may notice that the logo resembles Aquaman's belt... buckle?

[image: this is the image that helped us identify beofett's kid's underwear] [image: more ornate, but still similar]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: The icon / belt buckle also seems to be a stylized `A` for Aqua-Man.

Comment: @Raidri: or for Atlantis? (Does he come from Atlantis?)

Comment: "A" for - "Aquatic-animal-poop"..

Comment: @PaulD.Waite at least in the *New 52*, it's a royal jewel, so it's likely to be an A for Atlantis.

Comment: An 'A' stylized to look like a fish-scale.

Comment: I was wrong, technically. It's not one of the seven _Royal Jewel_ (actually, they are called _Dead King's Atlantean Relics_), but the symbol is seen in several of them.

Answer (score 14):

**It seems to be a fan-made *Aquaman* logo.**

There’s an *Aquaman* film set for release [in July 2018](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1477834/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). I found a [deviantART post](https://www.deviantart.com/cap1carlson/art/Aqua-Man-symbol-412194997) which contains some artwork very similar to the logo in the question, and is titled “Aqua Man symbol”:

[image: The DeviantART image]

I had a look using some reverse image lookup tools (Google Images, Tineye) for similar designs, and there weren’t many results. I suspect this is just fan art, not an official logo for the film.

Comment: Also... I never knew his _secret identity_ is Arthur Curry... How did he even come up with that? Maybe they have curry in Atlantis...

Comment: or curry has fish in it?