# Which font have they used for the 2020 paperback release of "The Lord of the Rings"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

I've finally started reading *The Lord of the Rings*, and noticed that the new 2020 paperbacks ([the *Mariner* edition from publisher HMH](https://www.hmhbooks.com/shop/books/the-lord-of-the-rings-boxed-set/9780358439196)) use a different font than the 2001 book I owned. I really like the new font. Does anyone know what it's called?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think font identification for a regular book is on topic

Comment: No matter how I squint and tilt my head, I just can't see this question as on-topic for this site. Does anyone know of a StackExchange site where this sort of question would be on-topic? I know that fonts, and in particular, font identification, are a favorite hobby for some people...

Comment: might be Amalia?

Comment: @Martha Why would it *not* be on-topic? True, fonts aren't on-topic per se, but neither is [underwear](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68005/whose-underwear-is-this) or [the meaning of English phrases](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11626/31394), but questions about underwear or meaning *in the context of a work of sci-fi or fantasy* are on-topic.

Comment: There are a lot of web sites where you can either upload an image of the font or answer questions about it to get an answer.  Here's one: [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com).

Comment: @Martha it *might* be on topic at [literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), certainly "Specific questions about the publishing process" are, and I've seen one recently about the printing process (I thought two, the other turned out to be a crafts, where I was torn between answering and calling it off-topic)

Comment: It's getting more and more common for font names being listed by the publisher in the *colophon* (the page, either in the front matter of the book or in the end matter, also listing the dates of the different editions, original title, copyright, ...). Have you tried watching there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's a font called **Minion**.

[image: Sample of Minion font]

http://www.identifont.com/find?font=minion

I took the sample picture you provided and went through the "Fonts by Appearance" Q & A, though I had to skip quite a few, and eventually I ended up with a list of possibilities.  This one seems to fit perfectly with the same test you provided.

If you can find additional capital letters, numbers, and symbols, you can narrow it down more accurately, but when I compare the letters in your sample with the shape of the letters in Minion, it seems to me a perfect fit.

Comment: Seems that apostrophe in that font is different: https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/minion (although there could be several ones)

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi yah, you're right. It's weird though, because every other character is spot-on.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi It's true.  Oddly, the grave mark over the `a` above looks like the acute mark over the `u` in Lugburz in the text, only reversed.  I tried out the font on Adobe`s site [Minion](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/minion#fonts-section) and blew it up to 120 pt size, and it looks like the acute and grave marks both have a slight upward slope on top, which causes them to look different from each other, not merely reversed.  This may be a stylistic decision by the publisher or a peculiarity of the way the typesetting was done.

Comment: @Kyralessa just checked for á and à - these two are present in Minion. And there also kind of custom apostrophe:  ’ <- it could be the one used in the book. So +1 from me.